# How to specify a schema name in the Postgres URL for connecting to a PostgreSQL database on Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, parse-server, heroku-postgres

I am connecting my parse-server application to a PostgreSQL database hosted on the Heroku-PostgreSQL service.

My database is with a schema called `gc` which is different to the default `public` schema on Postgresql.

I used the following to connect to the database from my parse-server application.

```
"postgres://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOSTNAME_ON_AWS}:5432/{DATABASE_NAME}?ssl=true"
```

But the issue was it was connected to the `public` schema but not the `gc` schema I wanted.

Is there a way to specify the schema name in Postgres URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can,

what you can do however is associate a schema search path with a database user, so if you want a different schema you'd can to use a different username to connect as.

SQL:

```
alter user fred set search_path to 'gc';
```

Comment: I think the parameter is just called `search_path`.

Comment: That was the answer! Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, see the answer from Wotchin

Answer (score 4):

I attach the parameter `options=-csearch_path=XXX` to the URI. It works.

```
psql "postgresql://user:pwd@127.0.0.1:6789/postgres?options=-csearch_path%3Dabc"
```

It shows the current schema below.

```
postgres=> show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 abc
(1 row)
```

And take notice that I use the URLencode for the character `=`. Its URL encoding is `%3D`. Otherwise, you can't get the correct result in the shell.

Here are some references:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

Comment: For JDBC, this is working for me: `?options=-c%20search_path=app,public,pg_catalog`